# Useful length of Pi?

Tags: pi, applications, decimal-expansion

Not sure where this really fits, so am trying Mathematics first.  Feel free to migrate to another StackExchange forum if more appropriate elsewhere.  So I was listening to a podcast yesterday that was discussing the progression of calculating Pi from original rough approximations of 3.x, to the current over 100 trillion (or maybe more). I can comprehend the desire to calculate Pi to as far as possible, but what is the practical limit of the number of digits in Pi's usage in science, engineering, chemistry, physics, etc.?

Comment: Only a few digits of $\pi$ are needed for applications.  Calculating so many digits is just a hardware/software challenge; cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Motives_for_computing_%CF%80)

Comment: It depends (particularly if your calculations involve subtracting something close to $\pi$) but usually slightly more than the precision of your other calculations is more than enough

Comment: One of my friends used to learn the digits of $\pi$ by heart. He knew a few hundreds of them. This may be a practical limit in psychology perhaps :)

Comment: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2016/3/16/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-we-really-need/#:~:text=It%20turns%20out%20that%2037,fantastically%20vast%20the%20universe%20is.

Comment: Use `$\pi$` for $\pi$.

Comment: Computation of the digits of pi is done mostly for fun, and as a way to test out computer hardware and parallelization algorithms.

Comment: [A] In School-level Physics & Chemistry & Biology , $22/7$ is "good-enough". [B] In Electrical Engineering , Civil Engineering , Relativity , Quantum Mechanics , Astronomy , 20 Decimal Digits is "over-kill". [C] In Cryptography , Chaos Theory , Statistical Analysis , Probability : It is not used like that Particular Number itself , It is used like a Source of Random Digits , where it is "the-more-the-merrier" [D] In Case of Challenging the limits & Setting records , it is "the-sky-is-not-the-limit" !

Answer (score 0):

I read once that you can get decently accurate results in astronomy just by using $\pi \approx 3$.

You can get a feel for how accurate your approximation to pi  needs to be with some calculus.

Area of circle is $A=\pi r^2$, so $dA=d(\pi) r^2$, so $\frac{dA}{A}=\frac{d\pi}{\pi}$.The relative error in the area is the relative error in pi. A 10% error in one will give you a 10% error in the other.

The force between two electrons is $F=\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$ so $\frac{dF}{F}=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}{e^2}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r^2}\frac{-d\pi}{\pi^2}=\frac{-d\pi}{\pi}$

$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}. \frac{d\zeta(2)}{\zeta(2)}=\frac{2\pi d\pi}{6}\frac{6}{\pi^2}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{d\pi}{\pi} $

A 10% error in $\pi$ is on the order of $0.3$ so a value between $2.85$ and $3.42$ should be fairly accurate.

Comment: For orders of magnitude, the estimate $\pi\approx 10^{0.5}$ is all you’d ever really need.